# What map library does this census visualization use?

Tags: gui

Link: http://projects.nytimes.com/census/2010/explorer

How can I also render that specific kind of map? Does it come from some popular library?

It doesn't look like Natural Earth or drawn with Mike Bostock's TopoJSONs. It says its from Google at the bottom right, but then why does it look different from maps.google.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lovely map. Down the bottom centre there's a link to http://www.socialexplorer.com/

> Social Explorer provides quick and easy access to current and
>   historical census data and demographic information. The easy-to-use
>   web interface lets users create maps and reports to illustrate,
>   analyze, and understand demography and social change. In addition to
>   its comprehensive data resources, Social Explorer offers features and
>   tools to meet the needs of demography experts and novices alike

This appears to be a commercial application written in Flex/Flash, which makes it a little difficult to tell which API it's using (though I'm sure someone can figure it out). It may be their own.

(Edit - Fiddler shows that it's reaching out to googleapis.com, so perhaps this is the deprecated [Google Maps API for Flash](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/)? Maybe I'm wrong about Social Explorer, which instead may just be the *source* of the data)

Alternatives to using this commercial product could include writing your own application using an API like [ArcGIS JS](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi), [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/), [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) or [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

Comment: Thank you very much for checking the details and suggesting alternatives with direct links. Much appreciated!